# Many to many mapping not creating correct tables

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a **Template** class

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual Template RelatedTemplate { get; set; }
    public virtual Field RelatedTemplatePrimaryField { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

And a **Field** class

```
public class Field
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public bool AllowEmpty { get; set; }
    public bool IsCollection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is it's not creating a many to many relationship, it just adds a FK on the fields table, I want a many to many relationship on

```
Fields ICollection<Field> Fields
```

and

```
ICollection<Template> Templates
```

EDIT:
If I remove

```
public virtual Template RelatedTemplate { get; set; }
public virtual Field RelatedTemplatePrimaryField { get; set; }
```

It works... Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where you must help EF to correctly recognize your relations. You can do it either by data annotations:

```
[InverseProperty("Fields")]
public virtual ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set; }
```

or by fluent-API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Fields)
            .WithMany(f => f.Templates);
```